# Custom distribution for UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, snapkit

I have the following `UIStackView`.

[image]

Here is the pseude-code:

```swift
let stack = UIStackView()
stack.axis = .vertical
stack.distribution = .fill
```

Blue, Yellow, Violet and Green views have their correct sizes (autosized labels or buttons). However, red one is being used to fill the remaining space.

I want that Violet one to fill the empty space instead of Red. Is there any way to specify which view should fill the empty space?

Comment: I don't know what's in the views in question, but I'd suggest you'll need to weight each view. Try making the red view's contentHuggingPriority higher than the violet?

Comment: Hey whatever you said is what I needed. Thank you. Feel free to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to weight each view using contentHuggingPriority.

Try making the red view's contentHuggingPriority higher than the violet.